# What is the scope of source model extend and implement?

Tags: magento-2.1, database, attributes, system-config, source-model

What is the scope of source model extend and implement between these two?

```
\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource

\Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
```

Attribute options are loaded via the attribute’s source class. The source class must extend \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\ AbstractSource. which further extend Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface.

but when to implement \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface is used when creating source model for system.xml configurations. And can be used with any other custom requirement.
AbstractSource is specifically for EAV attributes.